# Question Regarding Bootcamp and Windows 7

Tags: macos, bootcamp, smb, hfs, hfs+

I am possible going to install windows 7 on my iMac using the standard bootcamp setup and have a question about this setup.

I will store all of my large movies on the mac and will need good access to them, once windows 7 has been installed is it able to access HFS+ partitions at a reasonable speed and more importantly, will i be able to create an SMB share of the folders on the mac through windows?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed Windows 7 using BootCamp on my MacBook Pro, Yes, I am able to access all the files on my mac HD.